# Easier way to include code snippets

Tags: php

I'm using [Wolf CMS](https://www.wolfcms.org/), but I want to make it easier to include [snippets](https://www.wolfcms.org/wiki/howto:snippets).

At the moment one has to write this to include a snippet:

```
<?php $this->includeSnippet('scripts'); ?>
```

In here 'scripts' is the name of the snippet.

What I'd like to do is write a little piece of code that interprets this:

```
###scripts### as <?php $this->includeSnippet('scripts'); ?>
```

Cause the line of code is always the same, only the snippet name changes.

Would that be possible or am I asking the impossible here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use preg_replace

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I fiddled around with it but unfortunately I'm not getting the results I would like. I need to define a string upfront (if I'm correct) and the string would be different each time. So eg: scripts, contactblock etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function for this:

```
function includeSnippetsFromList($snippets) {
    foreach ($snippets as $snippet) {
        $this->includeSnippet($snippet);
    }
}
```

... and then call it like this:

```
$snippets = "snippet1,snippet2,scripts,specialSnippet,layoutSnippet";
// turn string to array of snippets and call function to include them:
includeSnippetsFromList(explode(",", $snippets));
```

The way you separate the snippets can of course be different.

If you want to have them embedded in a long text and wrapped like `###scripts###`, then you could use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-amm.php) to extract them:

```
function includeSnippetsFromText($text) {
    preg_match_all("/###(.*?)###/", $text, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[1] as $snippet) {
        $this->includeSnippet($snippet);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$text = 
"This is a text
that has snippets, like
###snippet1###
###snippet2###
###scripts###
but also these:
###specialSnippet###
###layoutSnippet###
This is the end of this text.";

includeSnippetsFromText($text);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to work with this. Is this based on the core of Wolf CMS? Cause it looks like it.

Comment: This is pure PHP, except for the embedded call to `includeSnippet` of course, which needs Wolf CMS. So the functions I propose just allow you to do multiple includeSnippet calls with one call.